# Convert Rails 4 has_many from condition with proc to where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following working has_many with a proc to capture a parameter for context:

```
has_many :subclass_point_analytics, :conditions =>  proc {"assessment_id = #{self.send(:assessment_id)}" }, :foreign_key => 'gid',  :dependent => :destroy
```

I am using Rails 4 and it is (rightfully) complaining about use of :conditions. After 30 minutes and lots of tries I cannot figure out how to convert :conditions  to -> { where ... } format. I would appreciate someone with knowledge of proc syntax to help me get that correct.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just do this:

```
has_many :subclass_point_analytics, -> (object) { where("assessment_id = ?", object.assessment_id) }, :foreign_key => 'gid',  :dependent => :destroy
```

object is your actual instance.
Also, watch out: the callable has to be the first thing (:conditions tend to be at the end)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Also suggest to rename 'object' variable to more domain specific name.

Comment: Just want to add that I have used this over and over where it was "necessary" and it worked like a charm. Thanks @Thomas for the answer.

Comment: how to do this in rails 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like this:

```
has_many :subclass_point_analytics, -> { where("assessment_id = #{self.send(:assessment_id)}") }, :foreign_key => 'gid',  :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: That is where I started too, but since that is missing the proc element, it doesn't work. My question is how to retain the proc element during the conversion.

Comment: It seems strange that the Proc is even necessary. Is it possible for the subclass_point_analytics to belong to the same model but have more than one assessment_id? If so, then how would you retrieve them with the association? It seems like it should be okay to drop the conditions altogether.

Comment: It is not possible for it to HAVE more than one assessment, but the condition is used as assessment_id is leading the primary key, and is part of a partition key. The performance difference without it is 1000x with the size of the data set.