# Access owner inside an ActiveRecord association scope block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, associations, rails-activerecord

I want to do something like...

```
class Person
  has_many :things, -> { where(attr: owner.attr) }
end
```

That is, declare a has_many association with a scope block, and inside that block I need to access the association owner, that is, a reference to the person model.

So if I end up calling `@some_person.things` the `owner` in the scope block above would be a reference to `@some_person`.

What can I use instead of `owner` in the code above to reference the association owner inside that block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like the approach to go for.  Lifted from here: [Convert Rails 4 has_many from condition with proc to where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279289/convert-rails-4-has-many-from-condition-with-proc-to-where)

```
has_many :things, -> (object){ where( attr: object.attr )}
```